# Can't connect to internet on static ip configured on router

Tags: networking, internet, configuration, static-ip

I have a static ip which is configured on a router.
I have a Dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop and am unable to connect to internet.
Within browser if I try to hit any url it is redirected to router admin panel instead.
While apt-get commands return an error of Clearsigned file isn't valid requires network authentication.
I have also tried installing Lubuntu and Linux Mint as well but got same error.
However, after dual booting into windows it doesn't seem to be a problem anymore as it is able to access internet.
I have gone through tons of forums which suggest changing /etc/network/interfaces but have got no luck till now, hence getting forward to ask this question.

Edited : added `ip a` and `ip route`
**`ip a` :-**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1f:d0:e9:95:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.206/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp2s0
       valid_lft 86242sec preferred_lft 86242sec
    inet6 fe80::9103:5146:1878:caeb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**`ip route` :-**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.206  metric 100
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to update it with output of `ip a`, `ip route` and the IP address of your router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DNS on your OS, from your local gateway's, [to Google's public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4.

Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: Thanks Deubledee, adding google's gateway solved the problem and I am able to connect to internet now. But can I know why default gateway was not able to make the connection?

Comment: It's not gateway you're changing. It's DNS the DNS server setting. It seems the routers DNS server is not working correctly.